# Can there be a tag synonym for star wars the phantom menace?

Tags: discussion, tags

Because I have already checked, can there be a tag synonymy called **star-wars-1** considering it doesn't exist and it is very accurate to which star wars movie we are talking about. Instead of it being **star-wars the-phantom-menace** as 2 different tags, could we have it like **star-wars-1**, **star-wars-2**  etc.

Reason for **star-wars-2** is because when you watch the start of the second star wars movie, that itself says star-wars-2, so why not?

Comment: Depending which version you watch, Star Wars Episode IV is simply titled "Star Wars"

Comment: But the opening scroll specifically refers to it as *"A New Hope"*.

Answer (score 3):

> So why not?

## It's unnecessary and confusing.

The tag for [star-wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) explains its purpose.

> An epic space opera film **series** created by George Lucas. Use this tag when asking questions about Star Wars. If you're asking about a particular movie, **also** tag the question with the tag for that movie (for example [a-new-hope] or [the-empire-strikes-back] etc).

Plus there will be arguments about *which* is "2"...Is it *Attack of the Clones* or *Empire Strikes Back*?

A tag should be **unambiguous** and [star-wars-x](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-x) ...isn't.

Comment: It is quite obvious which one it is: it says purely in the movie.

Comment: It's not "obvious". Ask anyone which was the first Star Wars movie and they will all answer "A New Hope". I might be in favour of [tag:star-wars-episode-1] but again, it's **redundant**. What is the overriding **need** for the tag?